# Query from a variable table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In my postgres DB, I Have some tables which their names vary based on the current date.

To be more specific their names are like these:

```
STATSDATA15_8_2019
STATSDATA14_8_2019
STATSDATA13_8_2019
...
```

I need an automated query that considering the current date, grabs data from the related table.

For example:

If the date is August 15th, I need:

```
select * from STATSDATA15_8_2019
```

And if it is August 14th, I need:

```
select * from STATSDATA14_8_2019
```

In fact i need an automated, dynamic query with variables.

Comment: you should create a [partitioned table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I really would recommend to follow the advice of @a_horse_with_no_name creating a partitioned table!

---

In case that you would stay with your design, you could use a function which dynamically creates the query out of a format string.

This, of course, only works if all of your tables have the same structure.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=124a5a13d91a289d3d3ac9e6b9ac157c)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_table_by_date(the_date date) RETURNS TABLE(content text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY 
             EXECUTE format(
                 'SELECT * FROM statsdata%s', 
                 to_char(the_date, 'DD_FMMM_YYYY')
             );
    END;
$$;

SELECT * FROM select_table_by_date('2019-08-15'::date);

SELECT * FROM select_table_by_date(CURRENT_DATE);
```

Comment: Dear S-Man

Really appreciate your helpful answer.
But i made a mistake about the tables' naming convention.
They are actually like this:
STATSDATA8_7_2019 , 
STATSDATA8_9_2019 , 
STATSDATA8_10_2019 , 
STATSDATA8_15_2019 , 

I'd be extremely grateful if you revise your answer based on this modification to solve my problem.
tnx a lot

Comment: Just change the date format string to 'FMMM-FMDD-YYYY'